# AbstractType plugin not being called

Tags: magento2, plugin

I'm trying to add a plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType`.

I've got a `di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType">
        <plugin name="plugin_abstracttype" type="MyModules\Module1\Plugins\AbstractType"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and corresponding `MyModules\Module1\Plugins\AbstractType` class:

```
namespace MyModules\Module1\Plugins;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class AbstractType
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        die('constructor');
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->logger->warning("constructor called");
    }

    public function beforePrepareForCart(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType $abstractType, \Magento\Framework\DataObject $buyRequest, $product)
    {
        die('prepareForCart');
        $this->logger->warning("called prepareForCart");
        return [$buyRequest, $product];
    }

    public function beforeCheckProductConfiguration(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType $abstractType, $product, $buyRequest)
    {
        $this->logger->warning("called checkProductConfig");
        return [$product, $buyRequest];
    }
}
```

For some darn reason, none of the methods (not even the constructor) ever get called.

I have already:

- `bin/magento cache:flush`
- `rm -rf generated/*`
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Unfortunately, none of these helped. Other plugins in this module work just fine.

Comment: Where is your di.xml file located?

Answer (score 0):

Try blow, it's working for me on Magento 2.3.4

```
/**   /Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml   **/

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType">
        <plugin name="rw_skuupdater" type="Rootways\AdminTheme\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Update" sortOrder="20" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Blow is around plugin file.

```
<?php
namespace Rootways\AdminTheme\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;

class Update
{
    /**
     * Item options prefix
     */
    const OPTION_PREFIX = 'option_';
    
    public function aroundGetOptionSku(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType $subject, callable $proceed, $product, $sku = '')
    {
        $result = $proceed($product, $sku);
        
        $skuDelimiter = '-';
        if (empty($sku)) {
            $sku = $product->getData('sku');
        }
        $optionIds = $product->getCustomOption('option_ids');
        if ($optionIds) {
            foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
                if ($option) {
                    $confItemOption = $product->getCustomOption(self::OPTION_PREFIX . $optionId);

                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setListener(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject());

                    $optionSku = $group->getOptionSku($confItemOption->getValue(), $skuDelimiter);
                    if ($optionSku) {
                        //$sku .= $skuDelimiter . $optionSku; // Updated by Rootways Inc.
                        $sku = $sku; // Updated by Vish at Rootways Inc.
                    }

                    if ($group->getListener()->getHasError()) {
                        $product->setHasError(true)->setMessage($group->getListener()->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $sku;
    }
}
```